# find all numbers which are divisible by 7 but not a multiple of 5

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Write a program which will find all numbers which are divisible by 7 but are not a multiple of 5 in the range of given input(min:250 to max:500) using SQL Server.

Output is like

```
252
259
266
273
287
294
301
308
upto 500.(**The result should be printed in a comma separated sequence**)
```

Comment: I take it this is homework?  What have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it most definitely is a homework question.

Comment: Clearly your instructor lacks understanding of what databases are used for. This is not something you should do with sql. And then having a delimited string as a result is just ridiculous.

Answer (score 1):

Consider using a recursive CTE:

```
with cte as (
    select 250 n
    union all select n + 1 from cte where n < 500
) t
select n
from cte
where n % 7 = 0 and n % 5 <> 0
option(maxrecursion 300)
```

Comment: thanks it works.but the result should be printed in a comma separated sequence

Comment: @AbdulMalik make an effort. You won't learn by asking others to do your work. And learn to ask smart questions. You posted "desired output" that is consistent with this script. You then noted the comma-separation goal as as a comment. So - which is it? Also, "program" and "script" are different things. You also mention "given input" - which means you probably need to write an application in a language you did not tag. That implies tsql is the wrong solution. In short, make an effort.